# kernel panics when glibc is changed

Tags: kernel, glibc

for a custom board, i made few changes to glibc in malloc code. replaced the glibc in the root filesystem and compiled the kernel to have this root-filesystem. When the kernel boots, i get a kernel panic with error:

```
  not syncing- attempted to kill init!
```

Here init is a link to busybox which is compiled dynamically.

I believe its due to the fact that the init process is not able to run because it might be trying to access glibc's functionality which eventually causes it to crash. Can  you please tell me if at this time glibc will be even present?, and if yes, how can i reach to the location of the fault as the kernel panic does not provides me useful info.

thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a straight answer to your question but here is what I always do to get more information to debug that kind of problem (kernel panic) and it always helped me. You should enable the Kernel oops module feature. When a kernel panic happen, this will give you a trace back of all routine that were called before that kernel panic. It prints it on the terminal. It is very helpful to see where the system comes from before the crash. I don't know what platform you are using but I'm using ARM and I can do that from the menu config. It's probably similar for other platform.